# Different and repetitive labels for charts with multiple facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart with multiple facets using the code below:

```
dat <- read.csv(file="./fig1.csv", header=TRUE)
dat2 <- melt(dat, id.var = c("id", "col1", "label"))
ggplot(dat2, aes(x=id, y=value, fill = variable))  +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
scale_x_discrete(limits=dat2$label) +
facet_grid(. ~ col1) +
geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))
```

and here is a minimized example of how my data looks like:

```
id label col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    3    1   0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1 
2    3    1   0.2  0.1  0.2  0.1
3    4    1   0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1
4    4    1   0.1  0.1  0.2  0.1
5    7    2   0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2
6    8    2   0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1 
7    9    2   0.2  0.1  0.2  0.1
8    9    2   0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1
9    9    2   0.1  0.1  0.2  0.1
```

The problem I have is that the labels do not show up as I expect them. The labels for the facet where col1 is 1 gets repeated for the facet where col1 is 2, which means the labels (7,8,9,9,9) are ignored. Also, when consecutive labels are the same, they only appear once. For instance, when the first label which is 3 appears, the second label which is again 3 is ignored. Does anyone know how I can have the labels as I list them in the label column?

Comment: Can you include an illustration of where you want the labels to be? Right now your code uses them as limits for the x-axis, when they don't match the values in `id` (which is mapped to the x-axis). It's not clear what you actually want to do.

Comment: Maybe you want `labels = dat2$id` instead of `limits`?